# Installing boot-repair 64 bit on my computer

Tags: grub2, 64-bit, boot-repair

I recently installed ubuntu in my computer, once it installed it was unable to boot windows saying that it was crashing due to the modifications the computer recently went through, then i heard about boot-repair which i also installed on my computer but now its telling me that I need the 64 bit version which I already downloaded and wrote it on a CD, but when i try to run the program both through the cd and just the downloaded file it never opens or starts running, any comments?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: simply run `sudo update-grub` command on the terminal.

Comment: This question is non-reproducible because the OP hasn't signed on to the site in over 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a live cd and installing the *boot-repair* again?

Or if its not working you can download the iso image file of the boot-repair [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/latest/download?source=directory) and burn it to a disk or use [*UnetBootIn*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/latest/download?source=directory) to make it bootable using a usb drive.

Comment: Boot-Repair ISO has not been updated for a couple of years as of June 2017. Better to use the ppa which has been updated and install into your Ubuntu live installer. Second option in : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair